# Printing index from a Pandas series

Tags: python, pandas

How to print index of a series using particular variable from any column? 
I have a Olympic dataset where index is country name and a column named Gold, I have to print country name where the value of Gold is 947.

Comment: what did you achieve so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with `index`:

```
print (df.index[df['Gold'] == 947])
```

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Gold':[947, 100, 20, 947]}, index=list('abcd'))
print (df)
   Gold
a   947
b   100
c    20
d   947

print (df.index[df['Gold'] == 947])
Index(['a', 'd'], dtype='object')
```